# Alamofire / AlamofireObjectMapper - How do I print error json from responseObject?

Tags: ios, json, parsing, alamofire, objectmapper

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method: Endpoints.login.method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .validate()
            .responseObject { [weak self] (response: DataResponse<User>) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let user):
                    cb(.success(user))
                case .failure(let error):
                    log.error(error)
                    cb(.failure(error))
                }
        }
```

If I enter wrong password then I am unable to print the exact error message which api is sending it to me.

```
po error.localizedDescription
```

I am always getting default message from alamofire  i.e. "`Response status code was unacceptable: 401.`". It should print the dynamic error message like `Invalid username and password`.

Btw I can use responseJson to print the dynamic error message using

```
.responseJSON { response in
                if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                    print("Success with JSON: \(response.result.value)")
                }
                else {
                    let error = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                    let errorMessage = error.object(forKey: "message") as! String
                    print(errorMessage)
                }
```

But how I should do the same with `responseObject` ?

**Update 1 -**

**Parameter**

```
let parameters = [
            "username": userName,
            "password": password
        ]
```

**Response**

```
Login Response: {
    error =     {
    };
    message = "401 - {\"success\":false,\"message\":\"Invalid user/pass\"}";
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the response of your API? As well as the header, cause some API developers like to put the errors in the header response.

Comment: @Glenn - Header is nil. I have updated my question with parameter and api response. So if I remove .validate() then it will go to success case and i can see error response in response.result.value. But if i add .validate() then it go to expected failure case but then i cannot print the error response sent by server.

Comment: @Tariq Hey i added an answer to this, that should help you out as to where to look for that error response, i had a similar problem myself as well while using Alamofire and thats how i got around this problem

Comment: Then you would need to parse the `message` data from your response. That's it.

Comment: Then i cannot add case .failure(let error) because that will never execute in responseObject. Instead i have to use responseJSON. I would like to use responseObject for the mapper

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting `Response status code was unacceptable: 401.` is because of `.validate()` method being called when calling request, what that does is checks for response code that should be in the acceptable range of 200...299 (according to Alamofire documentation as well)

Any response out of that range is gonna say status code was unacceptable, however it does not throw away whatever is sent from the server, it sits inside:

```
response.data
```

which you would have to decode yourself by doing:

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
```

that will return you a value of `Any` or throw an exception, check out this apple blog post for more info on this: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37